# ADB can detect devices but it can't detect device in recovery move

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp

I am using mac.
I am trying to install twrp on my Galaxy Note 8.0 GT-Nn5120, via adb. ADB can detect the device when in normal mode but when i boot into recovery mode, it can't detect the device.. What do I do

Comment: Are you using the stock recovery? It's possible that you have to use another recovery such as TWRP to use ADB in recovery. From my experience you need to install the recovery using ODIN.

Comment: I'm using stock recovery, I want to flash TWRP but I'm using mac so I can't use odin, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ADB in recovery mode, not with a stock recovery. You can only ADB Sideload which is used to flash zip packages (updates, gapps, etc). To install TWRP, you need to flash it in Download mode.

1. Download [TRWP](http://d-h.st/OBt) or [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/llebydmoq44ameo/CivZ-Touch-6.0.4.4-Odin.-5120-REV1.1.tar)
2. Boot in Download mode (Hold volume down then briefly press the power button. Press Volume up to confirm).
3. Download and unzip [Odin](http://www.mediafire.com/download/4axz7npy68s9h2x/Odin_v3.07.zip) then launch it.
4. Click on PDA or AP button and select TWRP file you downloaded previously (Should be in .tar format. If in zip, unzip it)
5. Click on Start button
6. When you see PASS, disconnect the phone and power on (Hold volume up this time: you should boot in TWRP recovery )

Comment: As a side note, a stock recovery doesn't allow sideloading flashable zips that are signed by anyone other than the manufacturer.

Comment: how do i use odin if I am on mac?

Comment: On Mac you'll need Heimdall. It's the Mac equivalent of Odin (Windows). @L.Tommy

Comment: lol can't install heimdall because "not compatible with this version of OS". I give up, i'll just settle for nova launcher and icon packs

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that